# How do I make my Mac send messages with my number?

Tags: mac, icloud, apple-id

Every time I send a message from my Mac it says it’s from my old iCloud email. I have since updated to a Gmail address for my iCloud but my messages and email on my Mac still have the old iCloud email address.

I have tried to go to settings and send & receive I have also tried signing out of my Apple ID and back in again.

Comment: Have you tried starting a new conversation? You can't easily edit what old conversations send from

Answer (score 2):

- on Mac open **Messages** application.
- Press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to edit **preferences**
- Select the iMessage tab

idk know what this looks like in Monterey, but you're looking for "Start new conversations from:"

[image]